# Hide REST data from user

Tags: security, http, rest, https

When using HTTPS to consume REST API, is there a way to prevent client user to view data inside the call?

I thought that HTTPS does this but as I run Fiddler, I see an option to install fake certificate and peek request content.

How to secure this?

Bartek

Comment: "How to secure this?" What is "this"? The fiddler specific issue?

Comment: _"is there a way to prevent client user to view data inside the call?"_ - no. What are you trying to do? What data are you sending in the request and why don't you want the client to see that?

Answer (score 2):

That "install fake certificate and peek request content" is called MITM. Mitm is Man-In-The-Middle attack which hacker tries to inject it's own [fake] certificate to user, user encrypts data with hacker's certificate, hacker decrypts data, stores decrypted data, re-encrypts it with server certificate and sends it to server, etc.

The only way for you to protect again MITM is check certificate and make sure it's valid certificate and if client is your own application your application should store your real certificate's serial.

So only prevention against SSL MITM is storing or validating your certificate before sending request.

Comment: Thanks for help! So 'hacker' will be able to view how application communicates with web api, he will be able to view what data we send, but unless he has that 'certificate serial' used by my app for encryption, he wont be able to send false data, yes?

Comment: No, if your client application (browser or custom made your own application) verify integrity of SSL certificate and make sure it's the correct certificate, 'hacker' will not be able to view data, because your application will not send data if fake certificate/wrong certificate being provided to it.